# .htaccess - redirect to page/dir, while all pages/dir are internally parsed as query string parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, query-string

**Scenario:**

I have a .htaccess file that is handling a lot of rewrites (I am aware it would be possbile/easier in PHP)

Everything worked fine
`/some/fake/dir/foobar` was internally rewritten to

`/index.php?some=fake&dir=foobar`

and any url containing a query string was stripped

so I wanted to make a "coming soon page" or a "under maintenance page" for any IP not matching the declared condition

**Example of what I've tried:**

I tried something like this, and some other variations.

```
# IF not from DEV address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
# AND not for comingsoon page or other assets
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\?comingsoon [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/comingsoon
# THEN send them to comingsoon page
RewriteRule ^ /comingsoon [R,L]
```

I've tried it in all potential areas of the .htaccess file to meet the conditions.

It seems to be the problem is getting redirect loops. the apache logs show it requesting the `/comingsoon` page then redirecting to the root directory `/`. I'm assuming because of the internal conversion of `/foo/bar` to `/?foo=bar`. But I can't seem how to figure this out where `/` is redirected to the "ghost" page `/comingsoon`

**below is the layout of the .htaccess file:** (code omitted to save time understanding problem)

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteBase /

# Forced https (should not effect the problem)
[...]
# To externally redirect /dir/index.php to /dir/
[...]
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
[...]
# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
[...]
# Prevent Rewrite on existing directories, files, and links
[...]
# Remove query string
[...]
# To internally rewrite directories as query string
[...]
# Custom error documents
```

Comment if full .htaccess is required to solve. Thanks!

**/EDIT:**

Please note, I have gotten it working fine with "real" files as my script prevents rewrites on existing files being requested. This is not the solution I'm looking for. My main index file is serving the dynamic content dependent on what the request_uri is rewritten to via query strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I solved it. had to check the %{THE_REQUEST} HEADERS for the hidden query string with `?comingsoon`

You can see the whitelist of files or directories I added if anyone runs into this problem as well :)

```
# IF not from DEV address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.5\.1$
# AND not for comingsoon page or other assets
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s(?:/\?comingsoon|/comingsoon|/assets/|/favicon\.ico|/google[A-Za-z0-9]+\.html) [NC]
# THEN send them to comingsoon page
RewriteRule ^ /comingsoon [R,L]
```